# Matlab - How to fill part of an image using imfill?

Tags: matlab, flood-fill

I have an image like this:

**img**

[image]

and I wanted to fill the bottom part using a mask like this as the location of seed points:

**mask**

[image]

This is what I tried but didn't work:

```matlab
img = imread('img.jpg'); maskImg = imread('mask.png');
[Gmag, Gdir] = imgradient(img,'sobel');
mask = imbinarize(maskImg);
[rows,columns] = find(mask);
bw = imfill(Gmag, [rows(:) columns(:)]);
figure, imshow(bw);
```

The error message is:

> Function IMFILL expected input number 2, CONN, to be a valid connectivity specifier. A nonscalar connectivity specifier must be 3-by-3-by- ... -by-3.

How can I fill the road part of the image above?

Comment: If you have the mask, you can just do `yourimg(mask)=yourvalue`

Comment: _"This is what I tried but didn't work"_: Please [edit] your question to include what output / error you got?

Comment: @AnderBiguri no I want to use the mask to fill the entire road part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not great and not highly reproducible for a variety of images but maybe something interesting can be pulled from this mess of rudimentary image processing techniques.

[image: Road Image]

```
Image = imread("img.jpg");
Mask = imread("mask.png");
Contrast_Stretched_Image = imadjust(Image,stretchlim(Image),[]);
Max_Filtered_Image = ordfilt2(Contrast_Stretched_Image,1,ones(9,9));
Filtered_Image = medfilt2(Max_Filtered_Image, [15 15]);
Filtered_Image = Filtered_Image > 200;
[Boundaries,Boundary_Image] = bwboundaries(Filtered_Image, 'noholes');
Largest_Boundary = Boundaries(1);
Largest_Boundary = Largest_Boundary{1,1};

imshow(Boundary_Image)
[Image_Height,Image_Width] = size(Image);
Binary_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width);
for Boundary_Index = 1: length(Largest_Boundary)

    X = Largest_Boundary(Boundary_Index,1);
    Y = Largest_Boundary(Boundary_Index,2);
    Binary_Image(X,Y) = 255;

end

Filled_Binary_Image = logical(imfill(Binary_Image,'holes'));
imshow(Filled_Binary_Image);
Image_Fill = uint8(~Filled_Binary_Image).*Image;
imshow(Image_Fill);
Mask_Fill = uint8(Filled_Binary_Image).*Mask;
imshow(Image_Fill+Mask_Fill);
```

The colour of the black unmasked portions can be changed prior to or afterwards. Complementary statements can be used to change the white and black regions.

## Four Types of Combinations

[image: Mask Image 3]

```
Image = imread("img.jpg");
Mask = imread("Mask.png");
Mask = (Mask ~= 0);
Image(Mask) = 255;
imshow(Image);
```

### White Portion Filled

[image: Masked Image 1]

```
Image = imread("img.jpg");
Mask = imread("Mask.png");
Mask = uint8(Mask > 0);
Masked_Image = Image.*Mask;
imshow(Masked_Image);
```

### Black Portion Filled

[image: Masked Image 2]

```
Image = imread("img.jpg");
Mask = imread("Mask.png");
Mask = uint8(Mask == 0);
Masked_Image_2 = Image.*Mask;
imshow(Masked_Image_2);
```

[image: Mask Image 4]

```
Image = imread("img.jpg");
Mask = imread("Mask.png");
Mask = (Mask == 0);
Image(Mask) = 255;
imshow(Image);
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: This was helpful. But I guess it means the flood-fill (imfill) algorithm cannot work with the triangle as the seed points to fill the road region.